# Merge two algorithms style in the same file

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e

Is it possible to put the two following algorithms in the same file. I tried several times but I did not succeed. Thanks for your help.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage[ruled,vlined,noresetcount]{algorithm2e}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode,amsmath}
\makeatletter
\newcounter{phase}[algorithm]
\newlength{\phaserulewidth}
\newcommand{\setphaserulewidth}{\setlength{\phaserulewidth}}
\newcommand{\phase}[1]{%
  \vspace{-1.25ex}
  % Top phase rule
  \Statex\leavevmode\llap{\rule{\dimexpr\labelwidth+\labelsep}{\phaserulewidth}}\rule{\linewidth}{\phaserulewidth}
  \Statex\strut\refstepcounter{phase}\textit{Phase~\thephase~--~#1}% Phase text
  % Bottom phase rule
  \vspace{-1.25ex}\Statex\leavevmode\llap{\rule{\dimexpr\labelwidth+\labelsep}{\phaserulewidth}}\rule{\linewidth}{\phaserulewidth}}
\makeatother

\setphaserulewidth{.7pt}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%



\begin{document}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \begin{algorithm}
            \DontPrintSemicolon
            \KwData{$S, C$}
            \KwResult{$X$}
            \Begin{
                    $X \leftarrow \emptyset$\;
                    \For{$C \neq \emptyset$}{
                            $A \leftarrow$ arbitrary element in $C$\;
                            $a \leftarrow$ arbitrary element in $a$\;
                            $X \leftarrow X \cup \{a\}$\;
                            $C \leftarrow C \setminus \{A \in C\ |\ A \cap X \neq \emptyset\}$\;
                    }
                    \Return{$X$}\;
            }
            \caption{Alg-1}
    \end{algorithm}
    
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    
    
    
    
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Selection algorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State initialization
    \State $\var{ini} = 4$
    \State $\var{init} = 0$
    \phase{Drifting phase}
    \Procedure {DriftingPhase}{}
      \For{each source~$S$}
        \State Broadcast IWD--
        \For{each IWD}
          \vspace{0.05in}
          \State Compute $\func{soil}(i,j) = (1-\Pi\psi) \times \func{soil}(i,j)-\Pi\psi \Delta \func{soil}(i,j)$
          \vspace{0.01in}
          \State Compute $P_r = (i,j) = \frac{f(\func{soil}(i,j))}{\sum\nolimits_{k \notin \func{vc}(IWD)}{f(\func{soil}(i,k)}}$
          \State $f(\func{soil}(i,j)) = \frac{1}{\func{soil}(i,j)}$
        \EndFor
      \EndFor
    \EndProcedure
    \phase{FindingRoute phase}
    \Procedure{FindingRoute phase}{}
      \For{each destination $D$ }
        \State $\func{MPRset}(D) = \max\{P_r(z) \cup z \in R\}$
        \State Send IWD-Rep $2$-hop away
      \EndFor
    \EndProcedure
    \phase{Final phase}
    \Procedure{finalPhase}{}
      \For{each source $S$}
        \State $\func{MPRset}(S) = \max\{P_r(z) \cup z \in R\}$ 
      \EndFor
      \State $\var{MPRRoute} = [S]$
    \EndProcedure
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    
    
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: x-post https://stackoverflow.com/q/76868505/2777074